# Problems getting custom elements with polymer working

Tags: polymer, web-component

I followed the getting started tutorial from the official polymer website here:

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html

I'm trying to test out web components and polymer, but I can't get a basic template working. I can't get anything to render on screen. Any ideas what I'm missing?

I'm 5000% all of my files are linked correctly.
I'm not seeing any errors in the log.
I'm using Polymer 0.8 preview from the github repo.
I'm using the latest version of Chrome ( 38.0.2125.122 ).
I'm using MAMP, so HTML imports will work.
I even included the web components polyfill just in case.
I can't find an article anywhere that suggests I've done something wrong.
It all seems so straightforward.

Custom Element:

```
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="app-list" noscript>
  <template>
    <ul>
      <li>Hello World!</li>
      <li>Hello World!</li>
      <li>Hello World!</li>
    </ul>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="app-list.html">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <app-list></app-list>

      <!-- etc... -->
```

Comment: 0.8 preview has some changes to the syntax for creating a new element. It's still baking and not really ready for public consumption yet. When you installed from bower you got 0.5.1 which is the current release and the one you should use for now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me in my Chromium-38 based node-webkit test set-up.  However, if I attempt to run the same code in Chrome, itself (with a local file for app-list) then the HTML Import fails due to a CORS exception and nothing shows on the screen.  I suggest you open the Chrome dev-tools and verify that the app-list element has been registered and contains your template in its shadow DOM:

```
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <app-list>
        #shadow-root
          <ul>
            <li>Hello World!</li>
            <li>Hello World!</li>
            <li>Hello World!</li>
          </ul>
          <content></content>
      </app-list>
```

(This is a re-creation of what you should see in the "elements" tab of the dev-tools).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the GitHub version to work properly from the master branch or the 0.8 preview branch. I installed it from bower and it worked fine.